# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2

Tags: java

I'm brand new to Java and my first assignment was to implement a "for" loop. I wrote this program in C++ and it compiles in Java, but I got an error at runtime. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class GlobalMembersMain
{

    public static Vector<Integer> get_prime_factors(int number)
    {

        Vector<Integer> primefactors = new Vector<Integer>();
        for (int j = 2; j <= number; j++)
        {
            if (number % j == 0)
            {
                primefactors.add(j);
                number = number / j;
                j = 1;
            }
        }
        return primefactors;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number;
        int count = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter integer to analyse:");
        System.out.print("\n");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = scan.nextInt();
        Vector<Integer> primefactors = new Vector<Integer>();
        primefactors = get_prime_factors(number);
        System.out.print("Prime factors are ");
        for (int a = 0; a < primefactors.size() + 1; a++)
        {
            if (primefactors.elementAt(a) == primefactors.elementAt(a+1))
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(primefactors.elementAt(a));
                System.out.print(" (");
                System.out.print(count);
                System.out.print(") ");
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Enter integer to analyse:
10
Prime factors are 2 (1) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoun
dsException: 2 >= 2
        at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
        at GlobalMembersMain.main(GlobalMembersMain.java:36)
```

Comment: dont use Vector, unless you really need synchronization.  Use List/ArrayList

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    for (int a = 0; a < primefactors.size() + 1; a++)
    {
        if (primefactors.elementAt(a) == primefactors.elementAt(a+1))
        {
            count++;
        }
```

Is exceeding the size of the `primefactors` collection.  By 2, in fact.

Change to `primefactors.size() - 1` to avoid this error.

Comment: OP should also not be using Vector among other things.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero based, which I imagine you are aware of.  What you may not be aware of is that in Java a `List` is backed by an array as well.  When you invoke `primefactors.size() +1` you are getting one more than you would possibly want.  For instance is pf is of size 1 your loop will do the following:

```
pf.get(0);  //returns the only value in the list  
pf.get(1); // element doesn't exist
```

Now the other thing is you do not want to use `Vector`, generally speaking in Java.  It is a synchronized collection.  What you want is List/ArrayList.

**OTHER CODE ISSUES**

```
public static Vector<Integer> get_prime_factors(int number)
```

this does not need to be static.  Also naming convention is camel case in Java so your function name should be `getPrimeFactors(int number)`

`GlobalMembersMain`

Should most likely be named `GlobalMember` as classes are to be singular in nature and I believe you added `Main` to indicate it was the class that holds the main function.

In your main function you would do this:

GlobalMember member = new GlobalMember();
member.getPrimeFactors(number);

Answer (score 0):

This is where the problem is:

```
for (int a = 0; a < primefactors.size() + 1; a++)
    {
        if (primefactors.elementAt(a) == primefactors.elementAt(a+1))
        {
            count++;
       }

//...
```

`primefactors.elementAt(a+1)` for the last element in your collection will throw the exception (AIOB).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that arrays, lists and vectors in Java are zero-based. In your case, the `primefactors` vector will consist of two elements, available at index 0 and 1 respectively.

The problem you are facing is that you try to access the element `primefactors.elementAt(2)` which does not exist.

One problem is the break condition in the loop:

```
for (int a = 0; a < primefactors.size() + 1; a++) { 
    // ... 
}
```

The first time, `a` will be 0, the second time `1` which are both fine. However, the loop will *not* break the third time, because `a` will equal 2, which is less than `primefactors.size() + 1`. Consequently, there will be a call to `primefactors.elementAt(2)` which does not exist and the program will blow up.

There is also a second problem inside the loop since you increment the loop variable by one during the comparison:

```
if (primefactors.elementAt(a) == primefactors.elementAt(a+1)) { 
    // ... 
}
```

Yet again, your program will fail if you pass 2 as an argument to `primefactors.elementAt(...)`